# What does this translate into? Ruby on Rails asset_host (http%3a%2f%2fohloh.net)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to fix a bug regarding http protocols. While under the hood I encountered this line of code:

```
def gravatar_url(md5, size)
  default_url = if ActionController::Base.asset_host.blank?
                  "http%3a%2f%2fohloh.net"
                else
                  "http#{"s" if request.ssl?}%3a%2f%2f#{ ActionController::Base.asset_host  }"
                end

   default_url << "%2fanon#{default_size(size).to_s}.gif"

   gravatar_host = request.ssl? ? "https://gravatar.com" : "http://gravatar.com"

   "#{gravatar_host}/avatar/#{md5}?&s=#{size}&rating=PG&d=#{default_url}"
end
```

Particularly, what does this mean? "http%3a%2f%2fohloh.net". I've never seen this before. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: huh? it's a URL - `http://ohloh.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means `http://ohloh.net`. The `%xx` entries are [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).